# How to get value of textbox eventhough it is assigned value at pageload function

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

This is Pageload Function code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //DropDownList Binding through bussiness logic
            Bussiness_logic.DropDownList_Bind(DDL_U, "SHORT_DESC", "UNIT_CODE", "UNIT_SOURCE");
            Bussiness_logic.DropDownList_Bind(DDL_Branch, "TYPE_DESC", "TYPE_CODE", "BRANCH_SOURCE");
        }
        if (Request.QueryString["File"] != null)
            {

                string fileNo = Request.QueryString["File"].ToString();
                Bussiness_logic.OpenConnection();
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("LINK_DATA", Bussiness_logic.con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FILE", fileNo);
                SqlDataReader dtr = com.ExecuteReader();
                if (dtr.HasRows)
                {
                    dtr.Read();
                    {
                        TxtFile.Text = dtr["FILE_NO"].ToString();
                        DDL_Branch.SelectedItem.Value = dtr["TYPE_DESC"].ToString();
                        TxtSub.Text = dtr["SUBJECT"].ToString();
                        DDL_U.SelectedItem.Value = dtr["SHORT_DESC"].ToString();
                    }
                }

                Bussiness_logic.CloseConnection();
                Label1.Text = "";
            }
      }
```

my problem is that it is not updating data it is taking only that values which were filled at the time of pageload function

Comment: That's because you are getting the values from SQL on each page load. Try using the `IsPostback` property in the `Page_Load` method.

Comment: On Pageload Function or Update Button ????

Comment: Could you post your whole `Page_Load` method?

Comment: Update my code.please check it. I am getting value in querystring from another page i.e. _Search.aspx_ and above code page is _File.aspx_ which is my start page .

Comment: What i want is i am fetching data fron another page and filling into textbox and DDL and then want to edit and save updated data but it is not updateung it .It is only storing that data which is comming through querystring

Comment: So, why don't you put you whole code in the `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` scope?

Comment: I tried that also but result is that when i transfer data fron another page to current page DDL are not filling correctly

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are not using the [`Page.IsPostback` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx). In the page life cycle, `Page_Load` will be executed before your button's `Click` event handler. Try wrapping the code that gets the values from SQL like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // get values from SQL
    }
}
```

Comment: No i have dropdownlist binding also `if (!Page.IsPostBack) { //DropDownList Binding through bussiness logic Bussiness_logic.DropDownList_Bind(DDL_U, "SHORT_DESC", "UNIT_CODE", "UNIT_SOURCE"); Bussiness_logic.DropDownList_Bind(DDL_Branch, "TYPE_DESC", "TYPE_CODE", "BRANCH_SOURCE"); }`
your code is not working because above two dropdown is not getting values from querystring variable